# After mdBottomSheet hide its remove ng-click fire

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

i insert in my code mdBottomSheet show and button that open it.

this is my mdBottomSheet code:

```
$scope.selectPhoto = function () {
  var options = {
    templateUrl: 'student-details/camera-buttons.tpl.html',
    scope: $scope
  };
  $mdBottomSheet.show(options);
}
```

this is my button:

```
<div layout="row" class="imageUpload" ng-hide="fileUri == undefined" ng-click="selectPhoto()">
  <div class="image" flex="15"><img src="images/photo-icon.png"/></div>
</div>
```

after i click the button the mdBottomSheet shown but when the mdButtonSheet hide 
i cant click again on the button, its not fire my function selectPhoto()...
actually when i click the button its do nothing.

what can i do?